# git-svn clone Errors using git 1.5.1 and 1.6.5 and Subversion 1.4.2

Tags: svn, git, clone

I am trying to integrate git into my workflow. I'm starting it by using it to manage working copies of code cloned off of a Subversion repository.

I've tried using both git 1.5.1 and 1.6.5. Both of these were built from source. I am using an official Debian package for Subversion. Using both versions of git yields the same error as seen below.

```
$ svn --version
svn, version 1.4.2 (r22196)
   compiled Aug  6 2009, 16:45:47

Copyright (C) 2000-2006 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.tigris.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_dav : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV (DeltaV) protocol.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme

$ git --version
git version 1.6.5

$ git-svn clone -s file://localhost/home/foo/bar/ .
perl: /tmp/buildd/subversion-1.4.2dfsg1/subversion/libsvn_subr/path.c:114: svn_path_join: Assertion `is_canonical(base, blen)' failed.
Aborted
```

Has anyone here experienced this or similar issues? I've googled this assertion error before and I do come up with results, but they don't seem to be related to git-svn specifically. Could this error be perhaps the result of trying to use `git-svn clone` on a path of the form `file://...` rather than `http://...`?

Comment: Try `git-svn clone -s file:///home/foo/bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I don't think you use `localhost` in an SVN `file://` URL.  My git-svn clones use `file:///` as the URL (so `file:///var/lib/svn/blah` to get at `/var/lib/svn/blah` on the local machine).

Comment: `localhost` works just fine for me when using regular svn commands. Your tip regarding git proved effective. All that was necessary to get this to work was to convert my URL file://localhost/home/svn/repository-name/project-name/ to file:///home/svn/repository-name/project-name/